# Do not execute the block if task is cancelled

Tags: ios, swift, block, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I have `MainViewController` -> `ThumbnailViewController` -> `ImageFullScreenViewController`. As their name implies, I have a main screen from which I go to a screen which shows collection of images and on selecting an image, I open the image in full screen.

In `ThumbnailViewController`, I download images as follows

```
private func getImages() {
        self.galleryImages.removeAll()
        for url in urls {
            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) in

                // errors are handled

                if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    self.galleryImages.append(image!)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
            requests.append(task)
        }
    }
```

In `viewDidLoad()` I call `getImages()`. In `viewWillDisappear()` of `ThumbnailViewController`, I cancel the ongoing tasks.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if isMovingFromParentViewController() {
        if requests.count > 0 {
            for request in requests {
                if request is NSURLSessionDataTask {
                    let task = request as! NSURLSessionDataTask
                    task.cancel()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I open `ThumbnailViewController` and immediately go back and if I open `ThumbnailViewController` immediately, I can see two copies of same image in some cases (rarely, but reproducible).

On investigation, I found that, cancelling the `NSURLSessionDataTask` in `viewWillDisappear` does cancel the task only, but not the completion block (which is the behavior). In some rare cases, the completion block is executed for the previous `NSURLSessionDataTask` thereby ending mixing with the response of the new `NSURLSessionDataTask`.

How could I handle this?

Note: `galleryImages` is a singleton property which I am reusing in `ImageFullScreenViewController` (`UIPageViewController`)

Comment: On a easier side :) why don't you simply check if image exists before adding it to galleryImages using something like galleryImages.contains( image) { ... }

Comment: Is `galleryImages` computed property or do it have any observers? Please, show declaration. There is nothing strange, that task sometimes already on the way to finish with completion; strange is how it able to mix received image with array of images in *new* instance of `ThumbnailViewController`. This can happend if `galleryImages` shared somehow.

Comment: Sorry. I should have mentioned. `galleryImages` is a singleton. I made it singleton, because, I am reusing the same array for the `UIPageViewController` in `ImageFullScreenViewController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should take care about release `ThumbnailViewController` object. Declare capture list with `weak self`, and it will, by additional, remove your issue in 99% cases (if you are not retaining `self` in some other places), though your model still not perfect with that singletone

```
private func getImages() {
    self.galleryImages.removeAll()
    for url in urls {
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { [weak self] (data, response, error) in

            // errors are handled
            // replace self. with self?.

            if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                self?.galleryImages.append(image!)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        requests.append(task)
    }
}
```

Comment: Revising the model as suggested solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your suggestion, even that isn't guaranteed to work correctly if a single view controller accidentally starts two fetches concurrently somehow.  IMO, a more robust approach would be to A. replace galleryImages with a new array in removeAll, B. store that in a new variable *outside* the block, C. capture that variable inside the block instead of self.galleryImages, D. run the guts of the block on your main thread so you won't have multiple threads mucking with a single mutable array.  That way, each set of requests always fills a new array and only the latest gets used.

Comment: @dgatwood you are right. I just pointed at important issue on existed code, and at unperfect model; I decided that suggesting concrete other model will be too broad